# Convert leading nan to trailing nan in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I concatenate with an array.

```
s = pd.concat([dataframe, pd.Series(array)], ignore_index=False, axis=1)
```

My problem is that the length of the array is shorter which result in leading nan.
I want to have trailing nan instead as the value correspond to the latest value at the bottom the frame.

Example:

```
   col1 col2 col3 
0    23   56   68
1    12   09   21
2    12   93   nan
3    12   64   nan
```

Should be:

```
   col1 col2 col3 
0    23   56   nan
1    12   09   nan
2    12   93   68
3    12   64   21
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `pd.concat([df, array.set_axis(df.index[-len(array):])], axis=1, ignore_index=False)` which sets the series' index to the last `len(array)` elements of the dataframe first and then concats. `array = pd.Series(array)` in your code.

Comment: @MustafaAydın You can add it as an answer.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma It's been closed as duplicated.

Comment: @MustafaAydın I don't think this is a duplicate question although its related to marked dupe but definitely not a duplicate. Lemme open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.concat([df, array.set_axis(df.index[-len(array):])], axis=1)
```

which sets the series' index to the last `len(array)` elements of the dataframe first and then concats. `array = pd.Series(array)` in your code.

to get

```
   col1  col2  col3
0    23    56   NaN
1    12     9   NaN
2    12    93  68.0
3    12    64  21.0
```

Answer (score 0):

What about shifting index:

```
d = dataframe
s = pd.Series(array)
s.index += 2 # or len(d.index) - len(s.index) 
pd.concat([d,s],axis=1)
```